# Is the following image the section of a Resilient channel?

Tags: drywall, sound-proofing

per this [post](http://www.soundproofing.org/infopages/channel.htm),

> Resilient channel is a thin metal channel that is intelligently designed to
>
> substantially improve the sound insulation of drywall, sheetrock,
>   plasterboard walls
>
> and ceilings. The channel effectively isolates drywall from the
>   framing studwork,
>
> which results in the weakening of sound waves substantially.

Is the following image the section of a Resilient channel?

[image]

The key is the air space at the right side, which cannot be connected to the connect studs. Is my understanding right?

Comment: Cross posted here https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/32946/10902

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is resilient channel, called RC1. The website you linked to has all that information.

Comment: The purpose of the unusual shape is to isolate the wallboard from the stud framing for sound control. (Wallboard on each side of a stud wall is like a drum...noise easily travels through the wallboard fastened to the stud.)